# Command less — differences

Tags: linux, shell

I have two codes and I'm pretty sure they do the same thing, but when I'm asked what's the difference between them I can't really think of a good answer. Can you explain it for me?
Here are the codes: 
`ls –l | grep "rwxr-xr-x"` and `ls –l | grep "rwxr-xr-x" | less`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls –l | grep "rwxr-xr-x"
```

This will show only files those who having file permissions `rwxr-xr-x`

```
ls –l | grep "rwxr-xr-x" | less
```

This one will also show the same but it will give you a list by interactive session. `less` is shorting the possible results into terminal that it got to fit in the space.

Answer (score 3):

1. print the output on your console screen
2. the output is piped to the program "less"; which visualizes the output (and allows scrolling,...)

If you want to know how less works; `man less` as @Avinash suggests